# best practices around Account sharing?

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule

this question might sound silly but it's around best practices and performance and security..

What is the best way to sharing account Internal Sharing...

```
1. OWD -- Public 
    or
2. OWD - private and sharing rule - account owned by internal user share with all internal user.
```

I know , making it public will increase the performance but is it major hit if I keep it private and create a simple non criteria based straight sharing rule ?

Comment: Are there other requirements here that would make you *not* want to leave the OWD Public, if everyone should be able to see all Accounts?

Answer (score 3):

One bit of advice from past experience --

If you think your org will be the "winning org" when and if you acquire another company or add another business unit wherein the acquired company's users shouldn't be able to see Accounts/Oppos/Cases/etc owned by users in your current org, then ..

- Start with OWD Private

If you think your org will divest a business unit to a third party but as part of the transitional services agreement (typically 90 days) the divested business unit gets to keep using the org but where the divested business unit's users shouldn't be able to see the rump user's Accounts/Opportunities/Cases/etc ..

- Start with OWD Private

You can always expand access with sharing rules as needed.

Comment: And this also saves a lot of regression if started with private. Had been in almost this very situation, where two BUs wanted to merge in a single org and the blocker was public read/write!